# When using doParallel in R, how can I get the line number where an error was thrown?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to figure out how to pinpoint the line where an error is thrown when using foreach and doParallel. Here's an example:

```
foreach.example <- function() 
{
    require("doParallel")
    z <- foreach (i = 1:2) %do% 
    {
       x <- i + 'a'
    }
    return(z)
}
```

So within the %do% there is a bug where i am adding a character to a numeric. (Everything I say here also applies to %dopar%,). When I run this I get:

```
> foreach.example()
Error in { (from test_foreach.R#3) : task 1 failed - "non-numeric argument     to binary operator"
```

I can't tell from this where in the loop I had the error line 3 is the foreach line, not the offending line. When I run debugger() I get:

```
> debugger()
Message:  Error in { (from test_foreach.R#3) : task 1 failed - "non-numeric    argument to binary operator"
    Available environments had calls:
1: foreach.example()
2: test_foreach.R#3: foreach(i = 1:2) %do% {
x <- i + "a"
}
3: e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)
4: stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr))
```

Note that frame 2 will generally indicate the whole loop so I can't find the line where the error was actually thrown.

If instead I run this without the foreach, I get useful information:

```
regular.example <- function() 
{ 
    z <- list()
    for (i in 1:2) {
        x <- i + 'a'
        z <- c(z, list(x))
    }
    return(z)
}

>regular.example()
Error in i + "a" (from test_foreach.R#12) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

and the debugger takes me to the line in code that threw the exception.

Any ideas on how to identify the line number with the excpetion when using foreach? Thanks.

Comment: You can get worker tracebacks by using the doMPI backend, but that doesn't include line numbers. And the tracebacks only show up in the worker log files, not in the error message produced by the master. I can't think of any options when using %do%.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your `foreach` call to include `.verbose = TRUE`

```
z <- foreach (i = 1:2, .verbose = T) %do% ...
```